# Why do Z-tests use standard error (using the know population standard deviation) and not only standard deviation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, z-test

I understand why a T-test uses the standard error, after all we are dealing with the inaccuracy of small samples.

$$T = \frac{\bar{x} - \mu}{\bar{s} / \sqrt{n}} = \frac{\bar{x} - \mu}{SE} $$

But why does Z-tests also uses standard error (calculated using the population standard deviation (sigma))?

$$Z = \frac{\bar{x} - \mu}{\sigma / \sqrt{n}}$$

I ask this because I thought standardization for normal distributions (not student`s T distribution) was done subtracting the average and dividing by the mean... In this case, the Z-Test formula doesnt make sense to me.

That would be the formula for normalization/standardization:

$$Z = \frac{\bar{x} - \mu}{\sigma }$$

No? I don`t get it.

Comment: With the test statistic in the z-test, its denominator is the standard error of the numerator. For the t-test the denominator is a sample estimate of that same standard error.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I think it would help for you to give what you believe to be the definition of standard error. I suspect the issue is a misunderstanding about this. People often have misconceptions about what standard error means (and that’s why a technical question I like to ask is the difference between standard deviation and standard error).